# Installation of power management API hooks on Windows OS using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel, power-management

Let me preface this by saying that my original goal was to determine the power state that a Windows OS is entering into before the actual power state kicks in. I asked a similar question on another thread for which I received a bunch of smirks regarding *why I need to know this*. So without going into lengthy explanation regarding why I need this, let me briefly say that the hardware I have connected to a PC will need this information for its own power management.

At this point I am also trying to avoid writing a device driver so instead I want to try to find a solution from a user mode/local service code.

OK, now back to the matter at hand. Since the Windows OS provides just the [basic power notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that, for instance, won't let me differentiate between rebooting vs. shut-down, or sleep vs. hibernation, I thought to implement a global hook on Windows APIs that initiate these power states (which are [SetSuspendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for sleep/hibernation and [InitiateSystemShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for rebooting/shut-down.) I also found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks) that explains how to implement the global API hook with C++/WinAPIs.

So being able to intercept a command for a power event before it happens the idea is to write into the system registry the type of the power event (see POWER_ACTION and SYSTEM_POWER_STATE below) and read it from the user-mode/local service code after it receives the WM_POWERBROADCAST notification.

I've never done global API hooking so before I jump into coding it, I'm asking for advice of professionals on this site -- what do you think, can this work?

Also a couple of technical questions about APIs themselves:

**1:** I did some research and it seems like most higher level power APIs on a kernel level boil down to either *NtInitiatePowerAction* or *ZwInitiatePowerAction* exported from Ntdll.dll. Both seem to do the same, but the question is, which one should I hook to?

**2:** There's a lack of documentation from Microsoft on those kernel level APIs. The only stuff I was able to find is this. Does anyone have any info to add to it?

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtInitiatePowerAction(
    IN POWER_ACTION SystemAction,
    IN SYSTEM_POWER_STATE MinSystemState,
    IN ULONG Flags,
    IN BOOLEAN Asynchronous
);

typedef enum _POWER_ACTION {
PowerActionNone,
PowerActionReserved,
PowerActionSleep,
PowerActionHibernate,
PowerActionShutdown,
PowerActionShutdownReset,
PowerActionShutdownOff
} POWER_ACTION, *PPOWER_ACTION;

typedef enum _SYSTEM_POWER_STATE {
PowerSystemUnspecified = 0,
PowerSystemWorking,
PowerSystemSleeping1,
PowerSystemSleeping2,
PowerSystemSleeping3,
PowerSystemHibernate,
PowerSystemShutdown
} SYSTEM_POWER_STATE, *PSYSTEM_POWER_STATE;

//Flags seem to be the these ones
POWER_ACTION_QUERY_ALLOWED
POWER_ACTION_UI_ALLOWED
POWER_ACTION_OVERRIDE_APPS
POWER_ACTION_LOCK_CONSOLE
POWER_ACTION_DISABLE_WAKES
POWER_ACTION_CRITICAL
```

Actual values for flags above can be [these here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**3:** I need this to work under Windows XP SP3 and later OS. It seems like all this stuff is supported since XP, but my concern is those kernel level APIs that don't seem to be mentioned in the official MSDN documentation.

So anyway, I'd appreciate to hear any insight on this?

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that all power transitions will originate from user-mode API requests.  Also, if two conflicting API requests are received at approximately the same time, how will you know which one the kernel decided to follow?  You may be better off biting the bullet and writing a device driver, at least that way you're using a supported process.

Comment: The difference between Nt and Zw functions is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565438%28v=vs.85%29

Comment: That is why I'm trying to intercept the kernel mode APIs. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not you can hook kernel mode APIs using the mechanism you're talking about, but if you can, I don't think the hook will work for calls coming from kernel mode.  (How could it?  The code you're injecting is in a user mode DLL.)

Comment: Yes, you have a point. The article I quoted states: "this hook is applied only to those processes that are linked to User32.dll." Although then it adds, "Actually, there are very few executables that are not linked with it." So I think it should work from a user-mode, which I believe Explorer.exe is a part of, so Start menu commands should be covered. It's a good point about the call originating from the kernel though. Any idea why the kernel would be calling power management functions?

Comment: It seems likely that if the user presses the power button it is a kernel-mode device driver that initiates the corresponding power transition.  I'm not sure about power transitions due to the system being idle, but they might well be handled in kernel mode or in native code - I may be wrong, but I think only win32 code, not native code, loads user32.dll.  Don't get me wrong, I don't know that your approach won't work, I'm just doubtful.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I have to admit defeat. I kinda got NtInitiatePowerAction hooked and was able to trap the moments when sleep or hibernation was triggered from a Start button menu or from a program, but that hook failed to work if sleep was initiated from the power options, say after N minutes of inactivity. So I guess, a partial success doesn't count...

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to hook APIs on a kernel level?

Comment: I believe so, but only on 32-bit versions of Windows.  64-bit versions have a technology called PatchGuard specifically designed to prevent kernel hooking.